# Flutter - drawAtlas circular cutout

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-canvas, flutter-custompainter

I'm trying to implement a circular cutout of an image and I am using [drawAtlas](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawAtlas.html) for it. Here is my implementation so far:

```dart
canvas.drawAtlas(
  image!,
  [
    /* Identity transform */
    RSTransform.fromComponents(
      rotation: 0.0,
      scale: 1,
      anchorX: 0,
      anchorY: 0,
      translateX: 0,
      translateY: 0,
    )
  ],
  [
    Rect.fromCircle(
      center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2),
      radius: 200,
    ),
  ],
  [],
  null,
  null,
  Paint(),
);
```

While it does work, it paints a rectangular image. I want to paint a circular cutout of the same image with some `strokeWidth`. Is it possible to do so using drawAtlas?

Comment: *"I want to paint a circular cutout of the same image  [...]"* - you need to clip your canvas then, btw, if you have single image without any transformations why dont you just use `Canvas.drawImage` method?

Comment: Actually, I am already using canvas.drawImage. This is for like `zoomed` view of the portion of the image, kind of like a magnifier glass interface that I am trying to implement. I want to make multiple magnified viewports within a single image.

Comment: could you add reference image or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent question! Although in your code, you are calling `Rect.fromCircle` to specify a clipping area, but it's still a rect (you are constructing a rect from a circle). The `drawAtlas` method only supports clipping rectangular areas from a larger image, as you probably already found out.

The key here is to use `canvas.clipRRect` to reduce the "allowed painting area". This is similar to adding a selection box in Photoshop. After doing this, anything that paints outside of the selection box will be ignored. In other words, by calling `canvas.clipRRect`, we will no longer be able to draw anything outside of the clipped area.

Presumably, after drawing a circular atlas, you might still want to draw other things to the canvas. And for those other things, you probably won't want to be limited to the clipped circle. To solve this, we can use `canvas.saveLayer` to save the state of the canvas before clipping happens, then do the circular clipping, then draw the altas, then finally, call `canvas.restore` to restore the previously saved state. Essentially this would clear the clipping, allowing us to draw more things anywhere on the canvas if needed.

**Solution:**

In short, the paint method might look something like this:

```
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Save the canvas state so we can clip it and then restore it later
    canvas.saveLayer(Rect.largest, Paint());
    // Clip the canvas, so we are only allowed to draw inside the circle
    canvas.clipRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 100, 100),
        Radius.circular(50),
      ),
    );
    // Draw the atlas (call your method)
    _drawAtlas(canvas, size);
    // Restore the canvas to its original state, so further drawings are not clipped
    canvas.restore();
  }
```

**Demo:**

[image: demo picture]

In the demo, when you press the button, the app will take a screenshot of the Flutter Logo inside the grey gradient container, and use that as the `ui.image` data. Then it will do the `drawAtlas` to draw a circular portion of the image to canvas.

Full demo code (paste everything to `main.dart` to run):

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _globalKey = GlobalKey();

  ui.Image? _image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            RepaintBoundary(
              key: _globalKey,
              child: Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: RadialGradient(
                    colors: [Colors.white, Colors.grey],
                  ),
                ),
                child: FlutterLogo(),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Press Me'),
              onPressed: () async {
                final render = (_globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()
                    as RenderRepaintBoundary);
                final image = await render.toImage();
                setState(() {
                  _image = image;
                });
              },
            ),
            if (_image != null)
              CustomPaint(
                size: Size(300, 300),
                painter: MyPainter(_image!),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image image;

  MyPainter(this.image);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Save the canvas state so we can clip it and then restore it later
    canvas.saveLayer(Rect.largest, Paint());
    // Clip the canvas, so we are only allowed to draw inside the circle
    canvas.clipRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 100, 100),
        Radius.circular(50),
      ),
    );
    // Draw the atlas (call your method)
    _drawAtlas(canvas, size);
    // Restore the canvas to its original state, so further drawings are not clipped
    canvas.restore();
  }

  _drawAtlas(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawAtlas(
      image,
      [
        /* Identity transform */
        RSTransform.fromComponents(
          rotation: 0.0,
          scale: 1,
          anchorX: 0,
          anchorY: 0,
          translateX: 0,
          translateY: 0,
        )
      ],
      [
        Rect.fromCircle(
          center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2),
          radius: 50,
        ),
      ],
      [],
      null,
      null,
      Paint(),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although I had to make a couple of modifications, canvas.clipRRect did the trick. Weird that when I tried with clip oval, it didn't work out. But I managed to make it work.